# Compiler : How is symbol table passed from source machine to target machine?

Tags: compiler-construction, backend, symbol-table

Symbol table is used by both front-end and back-end but how is the symbol table passed to back-end assuming that target code will run on a different machine? Would it be somehow "attached" to the intermediate representation or will it be included in the instance of logical address space?

Comment: Which symbol table, the one for linking or the one for debugging (assuming they're different in your binary packaging)?

Comment: @eh9 the one for linking and I'm asking for generic purpose, not specific to a single front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol table for linking is placed in the intermediate object-code file, with extension such as .o or .obj, depending on platform. See the article titled [Object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) for an overview and other links. Not only is there a symbol table there, but also things like relocation tables and dynamic link data, basically everything needed to ultimately get the code loaded into system RAM and executing.